# Receive "Cannot set properties of null" error when changing SELECT options using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a script to change the options of a second SELECT element based on the first SELECT element options. But the issue is whenever I try to change the second SELECT options, the console gives me the following error. **Important: This is a tiny snippet of code from my entire script and page.**

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')***

My HTML code

```
<select id="field_option-1">
    <option value="first">First option</option>
    <option value="second">Second option</option>
    <option value="third">Third option</option>
</select>

<select id="field_option-2">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
</select>
```

My JS code

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("field_option-1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("field_option-2");

select1.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var selectValue = this.value;
    if(selectValue == "first"){
        select2.innerHTML = "<option value='new1'>New option 1</option>";
    }
    else if(selectValue == "second"){
        select2.innerHTML = "<option value='new2'>New option 2</option>";
    }
    else if(selectValue == "third"){
        select2.innerHTML = "<option value='new3'>New option 3</option>";
    }
});
```

I tested this code in localhost and it works perfectly. But after I upload it to the server, the console is showing that error.

Comment: maybe there's a chance that the event handler function can't see the `select2` variable defined outside its scope in your real production scenario. Try to fetch the html element from scratch inside that function doing `const targetSelect = document.getElementById("field_option-2");`

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Thanks for your idea. Just tried this, but it's no go.

Comment: change your `var`s to `const` as var sets a variable without scope, this means that anyother code can overwrite the value of the var even if its not supposed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that this JS code runs before the `select` tags are rendered, it depends on where the `script` tag linking this file is located.
In any case, you can fix this by adding the `defer` attribute to the `script` tag if it has the `src` attribute, or by placing it at the end of the `body` tag.

Comment: I would agree with you.. but the OP had to be more accurate saying that he also got the error when adding the event listener to the first select. anyway I agree this is an option

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you dynamically modify the select2 HTML element, so the one saved in the variable is not valable anymore. You can try this in order to get the updated reference at each callback:

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById("field_option-1");
select1.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var select2 = document.getElementById("field_option-2");
    var selectValue = this.value;
    if(selectValue == "first"){
        select2.innerHTML = "<option value='new1'>New option 1</option>";
    }
    else if(selectValue == "second"){
        select2.innerHTML = "<option value='new2'>New option 2</option>";
    }
    else if(selectValue == "third"){
        select2.innerHTML = "<option value='new3'>New option 3</option>";
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="field_option-1">
    <option value="first">First option</option>
    <option value="second">Second option</option>
    <option value="third">Third option</option>
</select>

<select id="field_option-2">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
</select>
```